# How can I find out the seed key for my genesis account on a local testnet?

Tags: stellar-core

Since I am running a local testnet of stellar-core, I was wondering if there is a way to determine the seed key for the genesis account ? I currrently have only one account on my local testnet.

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be displayed in the logs after running `stellar-core --newdb`.